Unable to Set ShipFrom when using ConfirmShipment in the Amazon Orders SP-API
We have tried everything we can see.  Our last attempt added a 'shipFrom' block as mentioned in some Amazon samples.  The shipment update is accepted without error, however the 'Ship From' in seller central is always the same, default warehouse.  Anyone have any experience with this?
{
  "packageDetail": {
    "packageReferenceId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
    "carrierCode": "FedEx",
    "shippingMethod": "FedEx Ground",
    "trackingNumber": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "shipFrom": {
      "name": "Sikeston",
      "addressLine1": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "addressLine2": "",
      "city": "Sikeston",
      "stateOrRegion": "Missouri",
      "postalCode": "xxxxx",
      "countryCode": "US"
    },
    "shipDate": "2024-07-03T00:00:00Z",
    "orderItems": [
      {
        "orderItemId": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "quantity": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "marketplaceId": "xxxxxxxxxxx"
}


The docs https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/orders-api-v0-reference#packagedetail has a shipFromSupplySourceId not a shipFrom property, and it seems to be a Guid.

shipFrom was an old field I think, I recall never getting it to work either.

The confirmShipment API allows you to confirm a shipment for a particular order. The request body contains a packageDetails array which is the container for the packages of the shipment (of course your shipment can use just one package).
Per each package, you can set a shipFromSupplySourceId property which is what you are looking for.
In order to retrieve your supply sources, you must use the Supply Sources API. These set of API will let you CRUD your warehouses.
It will be sufficient to call the getSupplySources to retrieve the list of yours, and then capture the SupplySourceId value. This is what you want to set inside the previously cited shipFromSupplySourceId parameter.

Thank you for this.  We completely overlooked that library.  However, now we are confirming shipments on orders using the newly acquired GUID ID values, and the 'ship from' on the resultant package does not seem to change, at all.  It is always set to the default warehouse.  Any experience with this?
